# Can I have test environment for Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have website running with live EC2 environment. I need to work on some enhancements and changes. Can I configure the test/temp EC2 environment??? How to create this ? Please help. I am newbie.

Comment: Just buy more CPU time / instances?

Comment: so, noway to have like sandbox testing environment ? please confirm ...because i used such environment for mechanical Turk project????

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test changes to your environment/server without affecting the production server, create an amazon image (AMI) of the production server and launch an instance based on that image. You can then do whatever testing to that test server.